# How to detect an active roaming mode in web apps?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Are there any means to detect from the client-side JavaScript that the current connection is cellular, or even better, in a roaming mode? I would like to save users' traffic consumption by picking an optimal update strategy in a progressive web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) which can try and tell you the network type. Note that a device could be on wifi while tethered to a cellular data puck so it's accuracy is not guaranteed.

```js
let preloadVideo = true;
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
if (connection) {
  if (connection.effectiveType=== 'cellular') {
    preloadVideo = false;
  }
}
```

I would also suggest looking into the [Save-Data](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/save-data) API which can tell you if the browser is set to reduce data usage.

```js
if ("connection" in navigator) {
    if (navigator.connection.saveData === true) {
        // Implement data saving operations here.
    }
}
```